# Class 'Ratchet\Server\IoServer' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ratchet

I am following the tutorial here: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world.

I am trying to get this tutorial application (using Laravel 5) to work but I am getting this error when I try to run the chat-server.php script:

Fatal error: Class 'Ratchet\Server\IoServer' not found in C:\Users\riyazs\projectname\app\Console\Commands\chat-server.php on line 7

projectname/app/Console/Commands/chat-server.php:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer; 
use App\Chat;
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

projectname/app/Chat.php:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
}
}
```

autoload part of composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I ran composer dumpauto, then tried to run the script but still got the same error

Comment: @RiyazShaikh try to use it global namespace like so `\Ratchet\` (just try, dont use it in production, its not good practic)

Comment: You need to include the `autoloader.php` file in the `vendors` directory.  I'd also remove the laravel tags, all this is running entirely outside of Laravel and it seems to confuse people.

Comment: @GONG i put "use \Ratchet;" at the top and it did nothing

Comment: @user3158900 that made it work, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Missing:

require /vendor/autoload.php in chat-server.php;